# is there a way to change fixed element style when enter any section element on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I have a chat or go to top svg btn with white border and some of my sections element have blue and other white background

what I want to do is when the fixed btn enter the section while scrolling check its background
and add different classes in each case .
how can I do that in javascript or jquery ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the solution I was looking for I did it using Intersection Observer

```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    let options = {
      root:null,
      rootMargin:"-570px 0px -100px 0px",
      threshold:0.05

    };

  let Observer= new IntersectionObserver(changColor,options);
    document.querySelectorAll("section").forEach(section => {
      Observer.observe(section);
    });
  });


function changColor(elements) {
elements.forEach(el => {
   if (el.isIntersecting) {
    let elbg=el.target.dataset.bg;
 
    if (elbg=="blue") { //if section data-bg== blue
     
      // change svg button style
         document.getElementById("chatting_path_7").style.fill = "#fff";
         document.getElementById("to_top_Ellipse_4").style.stroke = "#fff";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("chatting_path_7").style.fill = "#034ea2";
        document.getElementById("to_top_Ellipse_4").style.stroke = "#034ea2";
    }
  }
})
```

}

Answer (score 2):

#### The easiest thing to do would be to have the fixed button have a background color that looks good on all sections.  That way you can just style it and leave it alone.

If you have to have the color change at different sections, there are a few ways of doing that, none are easy, and only a few would have good performance.

#### The best way of doing this that I can think of would be:

- Have the background of the `fixed` button be the default color.
- Add a class modifier so that when you add one class it changes the style to the new color. *Example: `.button` becomes `.button.red`*
- On each section that has to change the background of the button, add a custom `data-attribute` *Example: `<section change-button-bg="red">`*
- Then `on load`

  1. Set up a `.querySelectorAll(*[change-button-bg])` so that you can run
     a check on each of the sections.
  2. Add a global variable called `currentTarget`
  3. Set up an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) on all the sections.
- Have the callback function for `.isIntersecting` do a few things.

  1. Update the `currentTaget` variable
  2. Update the color of the button
  3. Add a scroll listener
- In the scroll listener watch the `bounds.bottom` of `currentTarget` to see which color it should be.
- Then in the Intersection Observer, if it's no longer intersecting, remove the scroll listener to prevent memory leaks.

#### Here is a working example.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  const changeBG = document.querySelectorAll('*[change-button-bg]');
  let currentTarget = null;
  
  const Observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, Observer) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        currentTarget = entry.target;
        addColor(true);
        window.addEventListener('scroll', watchTarget);
      } else {
        addColor(false);
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', watchTarget)
      }
    }
  }, {threshold: 0.15});

  for (const element of changeBG) {
    Observer.observe(element);
  }
  
  function watchTarget() {
    const bounds = currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    if (bounds.bottom < window.innerHeight - 80) {
        addColor(false);
    } else {
      addColor(true);
    }
  }
  
  function addColor(add) {
    const btn = document.getElementById('button');
    if (add) {
      btn.classList.add('red');
    } else {
      btn.classList.remove('red');
    }    
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}

button {
  position:fixed;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <section></section>
    <section change-button-bg="red"></section>
    <section></section>
    <section change-button-bg="red"></section>
    <section></section>
    <button id="button">Top</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks sir its work really good but i have  an issue  that its doesn't work when scrolling back to up

Comment: @yahyahaddad can you share with me where it's not working in a CodePen?